# Determine adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, differential-operators

Let $K\in D\{(x,\xi)\in \mathbb {R}^2 : x > 0, \xi > 0\} $ and $L (\phi)(x)=\int_0^x K (x,\xi)\phi (\xi)d\xi $ for $\phi \in D (\mathbb {R})$

$D $ is the space of testfunctions

I know that $\langle L\phi,\psi\rangle = \langle \phi, L^{\ast}\psi\rangle $ but how do i use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: just write out the double integral which is $\langle L\phi,\psi\rangle$, apply Fubini and see what you get. $L^*$ is a form similar to the one of $L$ (only the integral kernel is slightly modified).

Comment: Ok i have: $\langle L\phi,\psi\rangle=\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^x K(x,\xi)\phi(\xi)d\xi \psi(x) dx=\int_0^x \int_0^{\infty} K(x,\xi)\phi(\xi)\psi(x)dxd\xi=\int_0^x \phi(\xi) \int_0^{\infty} K(x,\xi)\psi(x)dxd\xi=...$ is this correct?

Comment: No, the second double integral you wrote down does not make sense; the integral bound $x$ is meaningless. You can replace the integral from $0$ to $x$ by an integral over the whole space by adding an appropriate indicator function.

Comment: $\int_0^\infty\int_0^xK(x,\xi)\phi(\xi)d\xi\psi(x)dx=\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \chi_{\{\xi\leq x\}} K(x,\xi)\phi(\xi)\psi(x)d\xi dx=\int_0^\infty \phi(\xi) \int_\xi^\infty K(x,\xi)\psi(x)dxd\xi=\langle\phi,L^\ast \psi \rangle$ can i do this?

Comment: Yes that's correct. (Btw, are you working with real-valued functions here? If complex, don't forget the conjugation of one of the argument functions in the scalar product!)

Comment: $L^\ast(\psi)(x)=\int_\xi^\infty K(x,\xi)\psi(x)dx$ do you mean that by integral kernel? As far as i know we are right now only working with real-valued functions. I'm sorry but i skipped last semesters functional analysis lecture and now I have problems in PDE. What a miracle...

Comment: I guess what I meant was that you can write $L$ as $L(\phi)(x)=\int\chi_{\xi\leq x} K(x,\xi) d\xi$. So $L$ is an integral operator with kernel $(x,\xi)\mapsto\chi_{\xi\leq x} K(x,\xi)$. The adjoint $L^*$ has the same form, but with kernel $(y,\tau)\mapsto \chi_{y\leq \tau} K(\tau,y)$. Notice the swapped variables...

Comment: Ok, this helps a lot! Thank you for your time.

Comment: No problem! $ $